# Gradle's Maven Publish plugin not publishing POM or proper version to Maven Local

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin, maven-publish

I am trying to get the Gradle [Maven Publish Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) to publish a snapshot version of my Java library to my local Maven repo such that:

1. The version of the jar is `1.0.0.SNAPSHOT-<timestamp>`, where `<timestamp>` is the current system time in millis (similar to something *like* `System.currentTimeInMillis()`); and
2. I log to STDOUT/console the full name of the jar being published, including the version above; and
3. A properly-formatted pom.xml is published to Maven local alongside the jar, so that any other Gradle/Maven projects can "pull it down" locally and fetch its transitive dependencies properly

My best attempt so far:

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

dependencies {
    compile(
        'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.0.12.Final'
        ,'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.10'
        ,'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.10'
        ,'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.0'
    )

    testCompile(
        'junit:junit:4.12'
    )
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
group 'com.me'

jar {
    baseName = 'my-lib'
    version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

However, with this setup, when I run `./gradlew publishToMavenLocal`:

- I do see the jar being deployed to `~/.m2/repository/com/me/my-lib/` but without a pom.xml and no `1.0.0.SNAPSHOT` version appended to it
- I don't even know how/where I would append the timestamp onto the version
- I don't even know how/where I would do a `println(...)` to report the full name of the jar being published

**Any ideas?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regarding **#3**, To install your artifact to a local repository you do not need the `maven-publish` plugin, rather the `maven` plugin

See [The Maven plugin documentation, specifically the Tasks section and the Installing to the local repository section](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html) with it, you can run `gradle clean build install`

It works for me with a build.gradle file as simple as this

```
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
```

Note, if you need to publish something other then the default generated jar then you need to change the `archives` configuration

---

Regarding **#1** appending the timestamp, move the version line outside the jar clause and change it from

```
version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

to

```
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT-${System.currentTimeMillis()}"
```

This is using Groovy GString (AKA string interpolation - **note the change from single quotes to double quotes**) to append the current time in millis to the version

---

Last but not least, regarding **#2** printing the jar full name append the following to the build.gradle file

```
install.doLast {
        println jar.archiveName
}
```

Essentially we're appending to the install task (the one executed in the top of my answer) a println of the jar configuration's archiveName (see [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html) if you want something else)

---

So all in all my build.gradle file looks like this:

```
group 'com.boazj'
version "1.0-SNAPSHOT-${System.currentTimeMillis()}"

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

install.doLast {
        println jar.archiveName
}
```